# Authentication issues between argocd-server to argocd-repo-server

Tags: devops, argocd, argo, gitops

I got an interesting challenge after removing the external load-balancer for the argocd server setup .

Basically we removed the load-balancer for the argocd server and made it clusterip
We use istio for the ingress routing, so we added a virtual service and assigned it to the  argocd server:port 80 using istio
When using the virtual-service url, I can access the argo UI via browser and its all fine.
Since we are using a virtual service, I can access the argocd cli and its fine.

The issue comes when I try to do a task where argocd server reaches out to other argocd services.
For example, when trying to add a repo via cli (using the virtual service), its failing with the below error:

```
time="2023-10-06T13:13:46-04:00" level=fatal msg="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: authentication handshake failed: read tcp argocd-server:52984->argocd-repo-server:8081: read: connection reset by peer\""
```

Basically the traffic is coming in via a virtual service, the authentication is failing between argocd-server to argocd-repo-server

Also I cant do a simple argocd appset list.  Same error as above.

Any clue on how to fix the authentication issue here people :pray: